# Entity Framework many to parent and child relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, relationship, ef-fluent-api

I have two entities A and B with the following relationship:

- A has 0 or more B
- B has 1 parent A
- B has 1 child A

I don't know how to implement this relationship (navigation properties, Fluent API...)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a c# writer, but I thinck you get the picture ?

```
class A {
    public List<B> possibleBList {get;set;}
} 

class B {
    public A Parent {get;set;}
    public A Child {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: When you add Id properties (primary keys and foreign keys) it's correct.

Comment: @makzr : Entity Framework Add's Id's and ForeignKey's by default ;-)